# minimum of convex function in different variables

Tags: convexity, global-optimization

Let $g_1,g_2$ be convex functions defined over $[0,1]$, and let $f:[0,1]^2 \rightarrow\mathbb R$ such that
$$f(x,y)=\min(g_1(x),g_2(y)). $$

I wish to know whether $f$ is convex. I do suspect that $f$ is quasiconvex.

A special case (which is in my interests) is whether
$$
f(x,y)=\min(|x-c|,|y-c|)
$$
quasiconvex or not, for $c\in[0,1]$.

I wasn't able to prove the claim for this case without tedious case analysis. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147475/proving-that-the-maximum-of-two-convex-functions-is-also-convex

Comment: @IgorRivin I'm concered with minimum of two variables, whereas your pointer concerns with a standart result in convexity analysis (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function), under "Convex function calculus" )

Comment: Why is this not the same, by defining $G_1(x, y) = g_1(x)$ and $G_2(x, y) = g_2(y)?$

Comment: @IgorRivin minimum vs maximum?

Comment: Why do you think it is? Think to the sublevel set $\{f\le 0\}$

Comment: Please do not edit questions to the point where an answer to the original question becomes irrelevant. I'm rolling back to the previous version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. Here is a graph of $\min(x^2, y^2+7).$
[image]

Comment: Very nice graph.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan Thanks. Apparently, someone hated it enough to downvote.